# Swift Escaping Unwanted Backslash Characters on JSON Encoding

Tags: json, swift, escaping, nsjsonserialization

I’m getting a bunch of unneeded “escaped back-slash” characters when I convert my `Swift` `Dictionary` object using `JSONSerialization`. It’s only happening on one of my `Key-Value` pairs - the one that has a `URL` in it:

```
"image" : "http:\/\/www.someWebSite.com\/images/\triangleImage.jpg”
```

I tried to run `JSONSerialization` twice thinking it might solve the problem - but it just crashes. `Swift` is not my main language so I’m not really sure how to fix this?

Here’s my code:

```
// Creating the Dictionary:
triangleDictionary["name"] = "triangle 01”
triangleDictionary["image"] = "http://www.someWebSite.com/triangleImage.jpg"
triangleDictionary["description"] = "a geometric shape"


// Serializing it to a JSON object:
do {
   let triangleData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: triangleDictionary, options: [.prettyPrinted])
   let triangleDataJSONString = String(data: triangleData, encoding: .utf8)!
   print("triangleDataJSONString = \(String(describing: triangleDataJSONString))")
}
catch {
   print("ERROR Serializing triangleData!: \(error)")
}
```

The output I get is almost perfect - except for those extra back-slashes:

```
{  
    "name" : “triangle 01”,  
    "description" : “a geometric shape”,
    "image" : "http:\/\/www.someWebSite.com\/images/\triangleImage.jpg”
}
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score -2):

Add this line in your code

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: I don't think that's a Swift statement...?

Comment: i just answered your question @Sirab33 :-)

Comment: No your code is a web thing - it's an HTTP Header. That's not what I'm working with here. I'm working on an Xcode project - totally different environment. Thanks anyway.